# How do I pass an additional object to a Django form so I can render some fields in the template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a form in Django where site visitors can submit "gear" to be included in a person's set of gear. Here's the URL to the change form:

```
# urls.py

path('person/<slug:slug>/gear/submit/', GearSubmitView.as_view(), name='forms/submit_gear'),
```

You can see that the person for whom the gear is being submitted is represented by a slug in the URL.

Here's the first part of the `CreateView`:

```
# views.py

class GearSubmitView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """Allows for third-party submissions for a pro's gear collection."""
    template_name = 'forms/submit_gear.html'
    form_class = GearSubmitForm
    success_message = 'Success: Submission added.'
```

And the form:

```
# forms.py

class GearSubmitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonProduct
        fields = ['product', 'version', 'setup_note', 'usage_start_date', 'evidence_link', 'evidence_text']
```

where `PersonProduct` is a junction table between my `Person` and `Product` models.

And the template:

```
# submit_gear.html

{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h2 id="content-header">Submit Gear For {{ person.full_name }}</h2>
        {% crispy form %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

where you can see what I'm trying to do. **I want to insert the name of the person represented by the slug in the URL in the form template**.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `get_context_data` method in your `views.py` as mentioned in [FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_context_data).

```
class GearSubmitView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """Allows for third-party submissions for a pro's gear collection."""
    template_name = 'forms/submit_gear.html'
    form_class = GearSubmitForm
    success_message = 'Success: Submission added.'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        person = Person.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs.get("slug")).first()
        data['full_name'] = person.full_name if person else ""
        return data
```

You can change the variable name with `full_name` in the html file. You can also pass whole instance if you need, I just minimize the data sending from view to html. I didn't run the code block above but it should something like this.

Comment: This did the job with one tiny change. I needed to add `self` to the filter like this: `person = Person.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).first()`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll edit my answer for people who visit the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the get_context_data method inside of your createview it will look like :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
   context['user'] = self.request.user
   return context
```

and on your template you will add :

```
{{user}}
```

Hope it help you out !

Comment: Good reminder of how to get the current logged in user into the `context`.